# Two different websites on Symfony2 and RoR on the same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

Is there a way to set up a website on RoR on main route on domain, let's say http://domain.com/ and set up symfony2 on subfolder (http://domain.com/symfony/)?

Comment: and how do you want the routing to work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure you can do that.
Assume you use nginx as a server. You just need to set up 2 locations.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;

  location /{
    proxy_pass http://YOUR_RAILS_UPSTREAM;
  }
  location /symfony {
    ;your symfony config
  }
}
```

I guess you will need to add some rewrite rules to match paths.